# google api v3 redirect_uri_mismatch Error

Tags: api, heroku, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i am try to get google account authentication for my app, but when i choose the account to log in i get the error redirect_uri_mismatch, 
at google console i create **Client ID for web application** 
first i try to run the app on local host with the following settings

```
REDIRECT URIS : http://localhost/myapppath/
```

but get the same error
also i try to host my app at heroku with the following **Client ID for web application** settings
[image]

but get the same error, i search many times on stackoverflow with no success to find a solution

this is my code, it is a test code to get the uploaded videos of a user

```
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '42965713xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'y9AWlbxxxxxxxDqdQwJ';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {
    // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
    // currently authenticated user's channel.
    $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
      'mine' => 'true',
    ));

    $htmlBody = '';
    foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
      // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
      // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
      // to retrieve that list.
      $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

      $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
        'maxResults' => 50
      ));

      $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
      foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
          $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
      }
      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    }
  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Uploads</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$htmlBody?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution after replacing this line

```
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

by this

```
$redirect = 'http://localhost/myappname';
```

i do not know why it is not working when it take the full path of the redirect class

Answer (score 2):

What credentials type you choose depends on the application you want to build. 'Client ID for web application' should work fine for you.

The URIs you specify in `Redirect URIs` have to point to the actual script file, like `http://example.com/index.php`. I don't think `http://example.com` is supposed to work.